# What is the "right" way to refer to javascript dependencies installed via bower in a yeoman project HTML file?

Tags: command-line-interface, yeoman, watch, bower

Yeoman's quickstart and package manager guides suggest using Bower to manage dependencies.

They get installed into

```
app/bower_components/[component_name]
```

The guide just suggests inserting a

```
<script src="app/bower_components/[component_name]/[relevant_file.js]"></script>
```

line into your html file.

That's fine. Except if that component has dependencies. Bower helpfully fetches those components, but, as far as I can see, doesn't give you a list of them and the order they need to be inserted into your code. (I know you get a list of what got installed when you do the install, and one could dig it out of a json file somewhere, but that's still just bower's name for the component, not the path to the actual file that needs to be referenced). Which means that, for a popular component like jquery-maonsonry I have to manually insert

```
<script src="bower_components/get-size/get-size.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/doc-ready/doc-ready.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/eventie/eventies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/get-style-property/get-style-property.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/matches-selector/matches-selector.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/outlayer/outlayer.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-masonry/masonry.js"></script>
```

All of which I had to go into and find the relevant js file name. Given that all these files are defined already in json dependencies files, and bower knows about them, is there a way the above code can be autogenerated. Either for me to put into my html manually, or a symLink that points to the output of a watch command. I'm aware require.js might manage this on my behalf, but is there a way to get around needing require?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote a tool that helps with this, [`grunt-bower-install`](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install). It's a grunt plug-in that works well with the Yeoman workflow. You manually run `grunt bower-install` after any change-up of your bower components. (After you install a new one, remove one, whatever).

I tried it out with `jquery-masonry`...

```
$ bower install jquery-masonry --save
$ grunt bower-install
```

...and ended up with...

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/outlayer/item.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/get-size/get-size.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-masonry/masonry.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

The reason this plug-in can't be more helpful is due to each package's `bower.json` file not specifying a `main` property. Without that knowledge, a script (like mine) can't reliably detect the actual package's core file.

These tools are all young. Given the free nature of Bower, anyone can register a package. The author has the choice of not mentioning dependencies, leaving out the `main` property, choose to include needless files, and we end up with a bit of chaos. Bower offers the dream workflow for end-users if package authors would just avoid these patterns. Hopefully they will pick up on these practices sooner than later.

However, that chaos aside, this is still *so* much better than it was just a couple years ago. You actually had to dig these plug-ins up for yourself, extract their .zip file to a folder, and find the real file you wanted yourself, anyway.

So, long story short, a tool like `grunt-bower-install` can help, but in the end, what you did originally is the safest approach.

### Just an update.

Yeoman's `generator-webapp` now includes this Grunt task, `grunt-bower-install`, out of the box. So, the result I described above is out-of-date.

#### The new results when using `grunt-bower-install` with `jquery-masonry`

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/get-style-property/get-style-property.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/get-size/get-size.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/eventie/eventie.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/doc-ready/doc-ready.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-bridget/jquery.bridget.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/matches-selector/matches-selector.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/outlayer/item.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/outlayer/outlayer.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-masonry/masonry.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

Comment: With regards to the update: do I still need to run grunt bower-install after each component update or it will now happen automatically (on e.g. bower install jquery-masonry) ?

Comment: Bower doesn't yet have postinstall support, but when it does, that type of functionality would be possible. Currently, you do have to run `grunt bower-install` after each change to your `bower.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just put some code on npm which puts your dependencies in an ordered array. 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/dependency-orderer

If you're not using grunt bower-install, or don't want to use script tags (if you're bundling your javascript, which you should be), hopefully this will work for you.

Keen to hear feedback, as this is the first module I've published.