# Script referencing with Yeoman/Bower

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, bower

I'm building an SPA with node, express and angular and have Yeoman organise my workflow. The question relates mainly to Bower:

When installing a new package (jquery, underscore etc.) or creating a new local js file I always have to manually reference it in my index.html file like this:

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
```

or something similar anyway. I was wondering if there was some way of automating this, especially given my app is single-page. Some people have pointed me to Require.js, but it's not ideal, plus I'm not the biggest fan of AMD.

What I'm looking for is something similar to how Meteor.js (or Rails server-side) does things: you just create a source file in your project and given it's in the correct directory, it will be included in your application without you manually setting any references.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module I ended up using was connect-assets (although snockets can work just as well for this). It allows referencing your js files in Rails fashion:

```
//= require a
//= require b
```

Third-party libraries managed by Bower have to be required individually. None of the automation solutions I checked got me what I needed. So...

```
//= require ../bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

Requiring your own code is spot on:

```
//= require_tree services
//= require_tree controllers
//= require_tree directives
```

Or simply

```
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `grunt-bower-install` (which is now included in `generator-webapp` when not using RequireJS) would help?

I have posted more details of how it works in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979062/what-is-the-right-way-to-refer-to-javascript-dependencies-installed-via-bower/17980965#17980965).

Comment: I'll check it out tonight. Thanks Stephen

Comment: Seems to work great, but solves only a half of my problem. How do I automatically import local files (i.e. MY code)?

Comment: Regarding `grunt-bower-install`, as the name suggests, it will only target Bower components. I think you might be expecting too much magic. Websites are just HTML, CSS, and JS. You are free to assemble that combination any of a bazillion possible ways. You might use Angular, Backbone, and jQuery. Or you might use just plain ol' JS. Or Ember. Or [etc. etc]. And with JS, you still have to put your `<script>` tags in order so everything works correctly. No script or build process or "magic" could accurately guess how you wrote your JS and put them in your HTML in the order you wrote for you.

Comment: check out Meteor: they've done it. The order of inclusion is dictated by directory structure: e.g. files under lib/ are included first, files in the same directory are included in alphabetical order except for `main.js` which is included last. True, this approach may not work for MPA's or hybrids, but for SPA it's spot on! There must be some way of doing that in Node, since Meteor is built on Node... I'll keep researching :)

Comment: With Meteor, you're using their conventions, which is a handshake you make before embarking upon a new app. In the case of "a web app" (versus a "meteor web app"), there is no such handshake. You would need to assemble tools yourself to do this according to your own workflow. Let us know if you find a tool that helps with this!

Comment: haven't tried yet, but connect-assets seems like a good fit for what I'm looking for to automatically reference local code. To be specific, I'm interested in `require_tree .` to recursively require everything in the current (js) directory. Specs mention that the order of inclusion is alphabetical which isn't ideal, but if it's drectories-first then I'm pretty much where I wanted to be, especially if I combine this with your library. If not, will have to `//require` every new js file, which is still better than writing `<script>` tags.

Comment: pardon, I meant snockets (which is included in connect-assets)